# Visual Studio 2008 Test Sets

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

Is it possible to group tests together so I can run a subset of all tests available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using VSTT, aka MSTest; You can use the [Test Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182463(VS.80).aspx#) feature.

Answer (score 1):

IN VS 2008 pro and Team lets you create a Test list where you can specify what tests to run.

you can also arrange your tests using Namespaces to specify groups of tests and then run the tests in that specified context.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways would be: by class and by namespace.

There is a run tests in context option, you can use to run a specific test method, but also a test class or namespace. It just depends on what you are pointing at. Open one test in the editor, and put the cursor on the namespace and check it out.